# Do psychological effects of sex discrimination have measurable effects on police-officer safety or productivity?

Tags: reference-request, sexuality, sociology

I would assume that sexual harassment and discrimination in the workplace are correlated with workers' productivity and self-reported sense of well-being.

I am not particularly familiar with the academic literature on the subject, but I would also assume that by now there is a body of literature either supporting or undermining this hypothesis.

Is anyone familiar with research that addresses this hypothesis, but specifically in the context of law enforcement?

For instance, I'd be interested in findings about whether sexual harssment is meaningfully correlated with:

- response times, traffic enforcement actions, or similar productivity metrics;
- unit cohesion;
- officer safety;
- mental health;
- employee turnover;
- use of paid time off;
- the career advancement of victims or perpetrators.